# Selenium webdriver erroring when checking if object exists being caught by webdrivereventlistener?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I've written a standalone function for my selenium script so that when I want to interact with an object I first check if it exists, to do this I've already specified things such the method to identify it by and the data to use etc, and have some methods like so: -

```
public WebElement waitforElement(individualThreadSession threadSesh) {

    String IDString = threadSesh.objLocVal; //This will be the string value to use to identify
    String IDType = threadSesh.objLocType; //This will be something like "CSS"/"XPATH" etc

    WebElement returnedElement = null;
    for (int second = 0; second < threadSesh.sessionWait; second++) {
        Action tempAction = new Action();
        tempAction.simpleWait(1);


        try {
            if(IDType.toString().equals("CSS")){
                if(isElementPresent(By.cssSelector(IDString), threadSesh)){
                    returnedElement = threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(IDString));
                    break;
                }
            }                       
            else if(IDType.toString().equals("XPATH")){
                if(isElementPresent(By.xpath(IDString), threadSesh)) {
                    returnedElement = threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath(IDString));
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(IDType.toString().equals("ID")){
                if(isElementPresent(By.id(IDString), threadSesh)) {
                    returnedElement = threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.id(IDString));
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(IDType.toString().equals("NAME")){
                if(isElementPresent(By.name(IDString), threadSesh)){
                    returnedElement = threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.name(IDString));
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(IDType.toString().equals("PARTIALLINKTEXT")){
                if(isElementPresent(By.partialLinkText(IDString), threadSesh)) {    
                    returnedElement = threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(IDString));
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(IDType.toString().equals("LINKTEXT")){
                if(isElementPresent(By.linkText(IDString), threadSesh)) {
                    returnedElement = threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.linkText(IDString));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("When trying to find the obj error encountered - " + e);}
    }
    return (returnedElement);
}
```

and this: -

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By myObject, individualThreadSession threadSesh) {
    try{
        System.out.println("actually check!");
        if (threadSesh.driver.findElement(myObject).isEnabled() && threadSesh.driver.findElement(myObject).isDisplayed()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        return(false);
    } 
}
```

But every time I run this it errors with the below and exits the test: -

```
Test failed with the following error: - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to find element with xpath == .//*[@id='main']/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span
```

Shouldn't this work?

I think it could be because I also have an WebDriverEventListener running which I'm guessing is catching this error and exiting the test etc, is there any way I can stop this eventlistener from listening during this waitforelement process?

If not is there a way I can check if the object is enable and visible or not without it throwing an exception?

The event listener is like so: -

```
        WebDriverEventListener listener = new AbstractWebDriverEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onException(Throwable t, WebDriver driver) {
                //Add in take screenshot here at some stage!

                if(!errorsCaught){
                    errorsCaught=true;

                    try{
                        driver.quit();
                    }catch(WebDriverException theError){}

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has encountered an error ");
                    individualThreadSession.this.endSession(individualThreadSession.this, t);
                }
            }
        };
```

More digging reveals that it looks like it is the listener picking up things before the catch does anything with it, so now I need to somehow work out how to get it to ignore the error!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had failed to spot one key line in my event listener,  the @Override! This was causing my listener to pick up all exceptions before any catch's I may have also put in, and my listener will just kill off the session and close the run as it should (even though I don't want it to do something in that case).

To get round this issue as I always go through the same route above to check for an object before interacting with it I can be fairly confident that this object will always be there before trying anything or timeout and exit gracefully.

So I've inserted a basic check like so: -

```
t.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase().equals("nosuchelementexception")
```

So if the error is a nosuchelementexception I don't bother doing anything with it and just go back into my loop, simples! :)

Answer (score 1):

If **findEelement** is unable to find the element you will get a NoSuchElementException. This is expected. Instead, try to use **findElements** that will return an empty list instead of an exception if no elements are present.

Two ways of solving your problem:

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(myObject).size()<0
```

or

```
private boolean doesElementExist (myObject) {
try {
    driver.findElement(myObject);
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

Comment: I tried replacing `threadSesh.driver.findElement(myObject).isEnabled() && threadSesh.driver.findElement(myObject).isDisplayed()` with `driver.findElements(myObject).size()<0` but that just always returns false, even when I know the object is present, and the old way picks it up as true...

Comment: Also, the second solution provided (wrapping it in a try catch) is what I've done, but my listener is catching the NoSuchElementException  and exiting the test and I wanted to avoid it catching just these exceptions...